# Call method which accepts an Action parameter synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, async-await

I am working with a library for which I do not have the source, and as such I can't decorate it with the async keyword and do things like `await` a `Task` (at least I don't know how to do that).  It exposes a method which returns an object (I'll call it "answer") and takes an integer, and a parameter of type `Action` where I retrieve that answer.  How can I wait for answer to get populated before my code continues?

```
Object answer = null;
remoteLibrary.remoteMethod(42, x => 
{
  answer = x.Value; //This might take a few seconds
});
//I want to do something here with "answer" AFTER it has been populated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a synchronization construct. And since this can take a few seconds it would be a waste to use a synchronous (blocking) one so I suggest an asynchronous one like `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
remoteLibrary.remoteMethod(42, x => 
{
    tcs.SetResult(x.Value);
});

var answer = await tcs.Task;
// use answer
```

The `TaskCompletionSource` exposes a task that you can `await` that wouldn't complete until you call `SetResult` (or `SetCanceled`, `SetException`). When it completes you get the result you set in `SetResult` so you don't need the dummy variable anymore.